# Getting Repeated values in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, inner-join

I was desperately trying harder and harder to get this thing done but didn`t yet succeed. I am getting repeated values when i run this query.

```
 select 
    tbl_ShipmentStatus.ShipmentID
    ,Tbl_Contract.ContractID,
    Tbl_Contract.KeyWinCountNumber,
    Tbl_Item.ItemName,
    Tbl_CountryFrom.CountryFromName,
    Tbl_CountryTo.CountryToName,
    Tbl_Brand.BrandName,
    Tbl_Count.CountName,
    Tbl_Seller.SellerName,
    Tbl_Buyer.BuyerName, 
    Tbl_Contract.ContractNumber,
    Tbl_Contract.ContractDate,
    tbl_CountDetail.TotalQty,
    tbl_CostUnit.CostUnitName,
    tbl_Comission.Payment,
    tbl_Port.PortName,
    Tbl_Contract.Vans,
    tbl_Comission.ComissionPay,
    tbl_Comission.ComissionRcv,
    tbl_CountDetail.UnitPrice,
    tbl_Comission.ComissionRemarks,
    tbl_CountDetail.Amount,
    tbl_LCStatus.LCNumber,
    tbl_ShipmentStatus.InvoiceNumber,
    tbl_ShipmentStatus.InvoiceDate,
    tbl_ShipmentStatus.BLNumber,
    tbl_ShipmentStatus.BLDate,
    tbl_ShipmentStatus.VesselName,
    tbl_ShipmentStatus.DueDate
     from tbl_ShipmentStatus 

    inner join tbl_LCStatus
    on
    tbl_LCStatus.LCID = tbl_ShipmentStatus.LCStatusID

    inner join Tbl_Contract
    on
    tbl_LCStatus.ContractID = Tbl_Contract.ContractID 

    inner join Tbl_CountDetail
    on Tbl_Contract.ContractID = Tbl_CountDetail.ContractId

    inner join tbl_Comission
    on
    tbl_Comission.ContractID = Tbl_Contract.ContractID

    inner join Tbl_Item
    on
    Tbl_Item.ItemID = Tbl_Contract.ItemID

    inner join Tbl_Brand
    on Tbl_Brand.BrandID = Tbl_Contract.BrandID
    inner join Tbl_Buyer
    on Tbl_Buyer.BuyerID = Tbl_Contract.BuyerID
    inner join Tbl_Seller
    on Tbl_Seller.SellerID = Tbl_Contract.SellerID
    inner join Tbl_CountryFrom
    on Tbl_CountryFrom.CountryFromID = Tbl_Contract.CountryFromID
    inner join Tbl_CountryTo
    on
    Tbl_CountryTo.CountryToID = Tbl_Contract.CountryToID
    inner join Tbl_Count
    on
    Tbl_Count.CountID = Tbl_CountDetail.CountId
    inner join tbl_CostUnit
    on tbl_Comission.CostUnitID = tbl_CostUnit.CostUnitID
    inner join tbl_Port
    on tbl_Port.PortID = tbl_Comission.PortID

    where tbl_LCStatus.isDeleted = 0
    and tbl_ShipmentStatus.isDeleted =0
    and tbl_LCStatus.isDeleted = 0
    and Tbl_CountDetail.isDeleted = 0
    and Tbl_Contract.isDeleted = 0

    and tbl_ShipmentStatus.LCStatusID = 5
```

I have also attached a picture of my result set of rows.
Any suggestions why this is happening would really be appreciable.

[Result Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g97qh.png)

Answer (score 1):

Typically this happens when you have an implicit partial cross join (Cartesian product) between two of your tables.  That's what it looks like to me here.

This happens most often when you have a many-to-many relationship.  For example, if a single `Album` allows both multiple `Artists` and multiple `Songs` and the only relationship between `Artists` and `Songs` is `Album`, then there's essentially a many-to-many relationship between `Artists` and `Songs`.  If you select from all three tables at once you're going to implicitly cross join `Artists` and `Songs`, and this may not be what you want.

Looking at your query, I see many-to-many between `Tbl_CountDetail` and `tbl_Comission` through `Tbl_Contract`.  Try eliminating one of those joins to test to see if the behavior disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `DISTINCT` keyword. It should solve your issue

```
Select DISTINCT ....
```

Wait as far as I can see your records are not duplicates.

HOWEVER

Notice the `CountName` column and `Shipment ID` column

The combination is unique for every row. Hence the values are unique as far as I can see. Try not selecting `CountName`.

Well if you have distinct rows its not a duplication problem. The issue is during the join a combination is occurring you don't want it to duplicating the results.

Either don't select `CountName` or you have a mistake in your data.

Only one of those rows should be true either 6 with Count2 or 6 with Count1. Likewise for 7. The fact that your getting both when your not supposed to indicates a logic mistake

Comment: the combination of CountName and Shipment ID is Unique for only 2 rows. The above query should return 2 records but its duplicating the 2 records to 4.

Comment: dude 6..count 2 , 7..count 2 , 6..count 1, 7..count 1. Those are the 4 distinct pairs I see

Comment: then what is the solution to this problem?

Comment: It seems like a logic error. Obviously which I can't help you with. Only one of the data should be true either 6...Count 1 OR 6...Count 2 .>> It can't be both as you assume only one should be printed